# Update the values of one column to other column based on condition

Tags: python, dataframe

The values from column A to be replaced to column C if the column A values startswith '2'

Data

```
   A        B      C
12525    1FWE23   na       
14654    22354    na
24798    32684    na
28945    45368    na
46456    46485    na
2D545    45346    na
A5D66    58446    na
```

Expected

```
   A        B      C
12525    1FWE23   na       
14654    22354    na
24798    32684    24798
28945    45368    28945
46456    46485    na
2D545    45346    2D545
A5D66    58446    na
```

Comment: I just tried out the below code but didn't got the expected output.                                                                         

df['C'] = list( map(lambda x: x.startswith('2'), df['A']))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# using loc identify the rows where column 'A' value starts with 'A',
# when true replace with 'C' with 'A'
df.loc[df['A'].str.startswith('2'), 'C'] = df['A']
df
```

```
        A       B   C
0   12525   1FWE23  na
1   14654   22354   na
2   24798   32684   24798
3   28945   45368   28945
4   46456   46485   na
5   2D545   45346   2D545
6   A5D66   58446   na
```